# Using PS3 Navigation Controller on PC

Tags: pc, controllers, playstation-move

How can I use the PS3 Navigation Controller on PC?

I want to substitute WASD with the Navigator to play FPS. I think it can be more ergonomic.

Comment: Did anyone have success on doing this? I don't care about wireless, so it could be done with the USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

MotionInJoy have a free driver for Windows PCs that you can use to connect your PS Move, Navigation controller and Sixaxis/DualShock 3.

http://www.motioninjoy.com/blog/playstation-3-motion-controller-ps-move-windows

I haven't tried it out myself yet, but I am planning to!

Comment: Tried without success. But it can be my bluetooth dingle.